# Command for counting and grouping into columns

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 B
2017-07-30 B
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 C
2017-07-31 A
2017-07-31 B
2017-07-31 C
2017-07-31 B
2017-07-31 C
```

Each line represent an event (A, B, or C) and the day it occured on.
I want to count the number events per type for each day.
This can be done with `sort file | uniq -c`, giving output like this:

```
  3     2017-07-30 A
  2     2017-07-30 B
  1     2017-07-30 C
  1     2017-07-31 A
  2     2017-07-31 B
  2     2017-07-31 C
```

However, I would like to have each event type as a column:

```
              A    B    C
2017-07-30    3    2    1
2017-07-31    1    2    2
```

**Is there a reasonably common command line tool that can do this?** If necessary, it can be assumed that all event types (A, B, C) are known in advance, but it's better if it isn't necessary.
Likewise it can be assumed that each event occurs at least once per day (meaning no zeros in the output), but here too it's better if it isn't necessary.

Comment: If you do a lot of data processing and aggregation, you might consider setting up a real database.  Postgres is free, mature, and very fully featured.  (I do such processing in a sandbox Postgres instance, which is [fairly easy to set up](http://verticalsysadmin.com/blog/setting-up-a-postgres-sandbox/).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "reasonably common" includes [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), then

```
datamash -Ws crosstab 1,2 < file
```

ex.

```
$ datamash -Ws crosstab 1,2 < file
    A   B   C
2017-07-30  3   2   1
2017-07-31  1   2   2
```

(unfortunately the formatting of this site doesn't preserve tabs - the actual output is tab aligned).

Comment: it gives me `datamash: invalid operation 'crosstab'`

Comment: @Roman Needs version 1.1.0. Looks like Ubuntu has been on 1.0.7 for almost two years.

Comment: @ViktorDahl, yes, the version is `datamash (GNU datamash) 1.0.7`. It's worth to add a note, I suppose

Comment: Note that the site does actually preserve formatting, it looks exactly like this in the terminal as well. However, this is, despite appearances, correctly aligned. It's just that `2017-07-30` is longer than a tab so it looks wrong. If you use something like `awk` or `cut` to process it, however, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version where we don't assign empty values to zero:

```
perl -lane '
   ++$h{$i[!$h{$F[0]} ? @i : -1]=$F[0]}{$F[1]}}{
   print join "\t", "\t", @h = sort keys %{ +{ map { map { $_ => 1 } keys %$_ } values %h } };
   print join "\t", $_, @{$h{$_}}{@h} for @i;
' yourfile
```

---

```
perl -lane '
   $i[@i]=$F[0] unless $h{$F[0]};
   ++$h{$F[0]}{$F[1]}}{
   @h = sort keys %{ +{ map { map { $_ => 1 } keys %$_ } values %h } };
   print join "\t", "\t", @h;
   for my $date ( @i ) {
      my $href = $h{$date};
      print join "\t", $date, map { $href->{$_} || 0 } @h;
   }
' yourfile
```

---

## Results

```
                A       B       C
2017-07-30      3       2       1
2017-07-31      1       2       2
```

---

## Data Structures:

- hash `%h` which has `keys` the dates and values sub-hashes whose keys are A, B, C, etc. and corresponding values are their respective counts on those particular dates.

---

```
  %h = (
       2017-07-30 => {
           A => 3,
           B => 2,
           C => 1,
       },
       ...
  );
```

---

- Array `@i` which stores the dates in the order they were encountered.
  We push the dates into the array `@i` only when it's not been seen earlier IOW, when it's seen for the first time only. The order is provided by the array position.
- Array `@h` has the uniquified keys after totaling all the "A", "B", "C", etc. keys from the hash `%h`.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ d[$1]; k[$2]; a[$2,$1]++ }END{ 
       printf("%10s"," ");
       for(i in k) printf("\t%s",i); print ""; 
       for(j in d) { 
           printf("%-10s",j); 
           for(i in k) printf("\t%d",a[i,j]); print "" 
       } }' file
```

The output:

```
            A   B   C
2017-07-30  3   2   1
2017-07-31  1   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain old **bash** version, using arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A values letters dates
while read date letter; do
 values[$date$letter]=$(( ${values[$date$letter]} + 1 ))
 letters[$letter]=1
 dates["$date"]=1
done <file.txt
echo ' ' ${!letters[@]} | sed 's/ /\t/g'
for date in ${!dates[@]}; do
 printf "%-8s\t" $date
 for letter in ${!letters[@]}; do
  printf "%s\t" ${values[$date$letter]}
 done
 echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:** `./count.awk input.txt | column -t -n`

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

{
    dates[$1] = $1;
    events[$2] = $2;
    numbers[$1][$2]++;
}

END {
    num_dates=asort(dates);
    num_events=asort(events);

    for (i = 1; i <= num_events; i++) {
        printf " %s", events[i];
    }
    print "";

    for (i = 1; i <= num_dates; i++ ) {
        printf "%s ", dates[i];
        for (j = 1; j <= num_events; j++) {
            printf "%s ", numbers[dates[i]][events[j]];
        }
        print "";
    }
}
```

#### Testing:

**Input** (complicated for testing)

```
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 D
2017-07-29 D
2017-07-30 B
2017-07-28 E
2017-07-30 B
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 A
2017-07-30 C
2017-07-31 A
2017-07-31 B
2017-07-31 C
2017-07-31 B 
2017-07-31 C
```

**Output**

```
            A  B  C  D  E
2017-07-28              1  
2017-07-29           1     
2017-07-30  3  2  1  1     
2017-07-31  1  2  2
```